# How to ensure a bash script is executable via web without being in /cgi-bin directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script, apache-httpd, cgi

My document root is

```
 /0/
```

i do not have any cgi-bin directories.

this is my virtual host with apache:

```
Listen *:80
DirectoryIndex 1

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /0
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias www.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

what i want to do is place a bash script in this directory.

the document root that is..

in it i will have.. ( test.sh )

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "test"
```

that is all.

i suppose i need to add this line to the

```
/etc/sudoers
```

file..

```
 apache ALL=NOPASSWD:/0/test.sh
```

is this all sufficient to ensure i can actually make my web site run via bash scripts and python scripts ?

if this works.. what would be to use of things such as

```
mod_wsgi and python for the web ?
```

i suppose i also have to make test.sh executable

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

if this works out and i set document root to

```
index.sh
```

what would be the point of wasting time with python for the web frameworks. or even python itself given that bash for the web would be more direct and thus faster. ?

Comment: Why you need to add apache to sudoers? With executable bit, you can run the script.

Comment: Apache **must** be configured to turn on CGI: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `<Directory "/0" >` entry in your `httpd.conf` file and add:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .sh
```

You should end up with something similar to:

```
<Directory "/0" >
    ...
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .sh 
    ...
</Directory>
```

Restart your server:

```
# service httpd restart
```

All the CGI files should be executable (`chmod +x <cgi file>`).  The file will run as user `apache` and group `apache`.

Point your browser at `http://<name or IP>/test.sh`

CGI isn't the most efficient way of running scripts as a new process (python or bash in this case) is started for each request, but it does make it easier to implement your scripts.  `WSGI` is a more efficient way of running Python than as a basic CGI script.